# Is there any method to increase the request time out for a rest api call in Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm creating a Recurrence Azure Logic App for calling a rest API one after another in the interval of 30 minutes. The scenario is, once I call the primary API, after the response comes as 200 (status code) then only the next API should be called. But the issue I'm facing is my primary API is taking about 3 mins 40 seconds to fetch the data. So every time the request fails as by default the request timeout is 2 minutes.

Please suggest a way to create this logic app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, you don't have any option in the Logic App HTTP action to configure the timeout duration, so it is probably not possible at the [`moment`](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/36679756-increase-request-timeout-for-logic-apps).

May be you should consider using Durable Function with the [`Function Chaining Pattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sequence).